# ffmpeg - filter_complex list too long

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg

Let's say I want to overlay a clock in the video using special font, color, etc to video that is aprox 30 min long. I end up with command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "
[0:v]drawtext=fontfile=/var/www/sites/manage/elements/digital-7.ttf:text='00\:00':fontcolor=white@1.0:fontsize=26:x=100:y=65:enable='between(t,0,7)'[tmp];
[tmp]drawtext=fontfile=/var/www/sites/manage/elements/digital-7.ttf:text='00\:01':fontcolor=white@1.0:fontsize=26:x=100:y=65:enable='between(t,7,8)'[tmp]; 
[tmp]drawtext=fontfile=/var/www/sites/manage/elements/digital-7.ttf:text='00\:02':fontcolor=white@1.0:fontsize=26:x=100:y=65:enable='between(t,8,9)'[tmp]; 
[tmp]drawtext=fontfile=/var/www/sites/manage/elements/digital-7.ttf:text='00\:03':fontcolor=white@1.0:fontsize=26:x=100:y=65:enable='between(t,9,10)'[tmp]; 
[tmp]drawtext=fontfile=/var/www/sites/manage/elements/digital-7.ttf:text='00\:04':fontcolor=white@1.0:fontsize=26:x=100:y=65:enable='between(t,10,11)'[tmp];
......." 
-map "[tmp]" -map 0:a -acodec copy -c:v h264 out.mp4
```

This clock is not the only overlay I have so finally I have end up with command 216kB long but this I cannot even run in bash because of argument list being too long.

I wanted to re-encode the video only once. Is there any other way I can do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you okay with having a solid color bounding box beneath the clock?

Comment: Yes, I can have that. What's on your mind?

Comment: Use the timecode generator in drawtext. If you're OK with the full HH:MM:SS.ffff readout, then a box is unnecessary, else use a color box, draw TC on top, crop it to show only MM:SS and overlay the result on base video. You could also split the base video - overlay the full TC on one input, crop it and overlay it on the 2nd input. But this might lead to frame drops and misalignment. Will have to test and check.

Comment: Great, thanks! This I think would do the job but I have to increase FPS for the videos as now it is 14.98 (15000/1001) and it seems that it's not supported by timecode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.mp4
-vf "drawtext=fontfile=/var/www/sites/manage/elements/digital-7.ttf: \
text='%{eif\:trunc((t-7)/60)\:d\:2}\:%{eif\:trunc(mod(t-7\,60))\:d\:2}': \
fontcolor=white@1.0:fontsize=26:x=100:y=65:enable='gte(t,7)'" \
-map "[tmp]" -map 0:a -acodec copy -c:v h264 out.mp4
```

Where `t` is timestamp of filtered frame in seconds.milliseconds,

`7` is desired `start time` of TC display,

`2` is output field width i.e. zero padding.

Comment: In matter of fact this is how I have soled that and it works fine!